# remove duplicated data in list C#?

Tags: c#

I have list with duplicated values, what I'm trying to do is to remove the data that is duplicate. If you look at the list data you will see that 'proj5,9,2013,FC,5558', for example, is duplicate.
update p is a `ReportByProjectModel`

```
class ReportByProjectModel
{
        public string projectID { get; set; }
        public int month { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
}
List<ReportByProjectModel> uniqueProjectList = p.Distinct().ToList();

System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("data list Distinct");

foreach (var d in uniqueProjectList.OrderBy(t => t.projectID).Distinct())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(d.projectID + "," + d.month + "," + d.year + "," + d.type + "," + d.value);
}
```

The list data:

```
Proj1,4,2013,FC,1001
Proj1,5,2013,FC,664
Proj1,5,2014,FC,5850
Proj1,6,2013,FC,6651
Proj1,7,2013,FC,1785
Proj1,8,2013,FC,5907
Proj1,9,2013,FC,36582
Proj1,10,2013,FC,57170
Proj1,11,2013,FC,46002
Proj1,12,2013,FC,36758
proj2,10,2013,FC,291
proj2,10,2013,FC,291
Proj3,10,2013,FC,1440
Proj3,11,2013,FC,4105
Proj3,12,2013,FC,3223
Proj3,10,2013,FC,1440
Proj3,11,2013,FC,4105
Proj3,12,2013,FC,3223
Proj4,10,2013,FC,646
Proj4,11,2013,FC,1400
Proj4,12,2013,FC,350
Proj4,10,2013,FC,646
Proj4,11,2013,FC,1400
Proj4,12,2013,FC,350
proj5,9,2013,FC,5558
proj5,10,2013,FC,31168
proj5,11,2013,FC,29807
proj5,12,2013,FC,23329
proj5,9,2013,FC,5558
proj5,10,2013,FC,31168
proj5,11,2013,FC,29807
proj5,12,2013,FC,23329
proj6,10,2013,FC,13455
proj6,11,2013,FC,24313
proj6,12,2013,FC,10116
proj6,10,2013,FC,13455
proj6,11,2013,FC,24313
proj6,12,2013,FC,10116
Proj7,11,2013,FC,12834
Proj7,12,2013,FC,697
proj8,1,2014,FC,20000
proj8,2,2014,FC,4250
proj8,3,2014,FC,1250
proj8,4,2014,FC,2398
proj8,11,2013,FC,7339
proj8,12,2013,FC,13038
```

Comment: Please show what is p here

Comment: view this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255121/get-list-of-distinct-values-in-listfoo

Comment: p has to be some sort of Collection, not a class...?

Comment: yes it is collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) uses the .Equals() and .GetHashCode() methods of the objects you're sorting.

The base implementation of this is [ReferenceEquals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx). I would suggest [overriding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx) these methods in your ReportByProjectModel class.

If you do this when your .Distinct() is called whether or not the entities are the same will be based on their properties rather than their references and duplicates will be filtered out.

```
public class ReportByProjectModel
{
        public string projectID { get; set; }
        public int month { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter is the wrong type then return false.
        ReportByProjectModel p = obj as TwoDPoint;
        if (p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return obj.projectID  == p.projectID
           && obj.month == p.month 
           && obj.year == p.year
           && obj.type == p.type;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Concat(projectID, "|", month, "|", year "|", type).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% about my implementation of GetHashCode, the idea is to create a unique key for this object (based on the values which make it unique). As you know your solution you could probably come up with a better mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Implement `IEquatable<T>` on `ReportByProjectModel` and `Distinct()` should function as you want it to.

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of
>   the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface.

More info: [Enumerable.Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Alternatively you could use a [DistinctBy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300088/distinct-with-lambda/1300116#1300116) method.

Comment: You could also perform a GroupBy on all columns to eliminate the duplicates

Comment: @Terence it would be nice to see that solution too

Answer (score -1):

Use distinct.

```
uniquePojectList = uniqueProjectList.Distinct();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: The OP is using Distinct already.

Comment: Distinct uses the default equality comparison which will not work as references are not equal...

Comment: not correctly, I didn't read through his entire code, but his initial linq query uses distinct on one field. So by using distinct on his current list to remove exact matches, it works correcly, just tested it...