# Get Unique Item only Azure

Tags: c#, linq, azure

I have this Azure Model called Matches where I have `OrderId` and `MatchedOrderId`like this

```
    public String OrderId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PartitionKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.PartitionKey = value;
        }
    }

    public String MatchedOrderId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RowKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RowKey = value;
        }
    }
```

So when I have two orders and they match I make two entries in this table. Making two entries is so that I can charge Organizations on the number of matches they have.

Now I want to display the number of matches, what I have been doing before is Getting all the matches in this Model like this

```
 public static IEnumerable<Match> GetAll()
 {
    return TableHelper.GetAll<Match>();
 }
```

But now I want to show the actual matches. So what I want to show is just one entry for the two entries I created. After getting all the matches like this

`List<Match> matches = Matches.GetAll();`

Is there a Linq query that can give me what I want?

It is not the duplicate of what has mentioned, because in that the records are identical but here the Entries are different. So an example is,

Entry 1:

```
OrderId: "xyz"
MatchedOrderId: "abc"
```

Entry 2:

```
OrderId: "abc"
MatchedOrderId: "xyz"
```

If I do simple Distinct it won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of distinct values in List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255121/get-a-list-of-distinct-values-in-list)

Comment: @HimBromBeere check my explanation to see how it is not a duplicate and then if you are satisfied please remove the close tag

Comment: So you want to handle `OrderId = "xyz"` and `MatchOrderId = "abc"` to be equal? I don´t see any rule that would correspond to this. Or do you mean as the `OrderId`are equal the two entries should be equal? Than it IS a duplicate, however maybe of another question.

Comment: I want to see if in both the entries if(entry1.orderId == entry2.MatchedOrderId && entry2.OrderId == entry1.MatchedOrderId) if this is true then only add one of the two entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Distinct`-method that has the `IEqualityComparer`-overload to define what equality means:

```
var result = matches.Distinct(new EqualityComparer());

class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Matches> {
    public bool Equals(Matches m1, Matches m2) { return m1.OrderId == m2.MatchedOrderId && m2.OrderId == m1.MatchedOrderId ; }
    public int GetHashCode(Matches m) { return 17 * m.OrderId.GetHashCode() + m.MatchOrderId.GetHashCode(); }
}
```

It is important to implement the `Equals`- and the `GetHashCode`-method on `IEqualityComparer`.

EDIT: Obviously the above hashcode is not good, so we take another one that is able to handle swappable properties:

```
return m.OrderId.GetHashCode() + m.MatchOrderId.GetHasCode();
```

The reason why we also need to implement this method is when comparing two instances before any call to `Equals` the hashcode for two instances is compared, which serves as some kind of pre-indicator if the instances might be equal. This might be in particular helpful when the actual check for equality has much logic and contains of comparisons for many different properties. Further read on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden).

Comment: What happens if you replace the return-value for `GetHashCode` by any conatnt value (not recommended, just for testing though)?

Comment: Still not good enough, the value I get when I am debugging is this 1782894113

Comment: This value should be equal for both instances of `Matches`, check this first.

Comment: No they are not the same. So here is the data                MatchedOrderId: "8587469456533746881chvh"
OrderId : "8587469456465955838w6pu"
HashValues:  1454038096

OrderId: "8587469456533746881chvh"
MatchedOrderId : "8587469456465955838w6pu"
HashValues:  -1656329112

Comment: That is working. Thanks a lot! I have some reading to do on why we have to have GetHashCode().