# C# Get Value when property Name is Equal to Variable when Object is Not a list

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

Please excuse me as I am not really sure if I am asking this the correct way.  I need to get the value of a field, when the field name is "dynamic" and is equal to another variable.

I tried this:
Here are my using statements:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Interop.QBFC13;
using CtixQBIntegration.Session_Framework;
using CTixQBIntegration.ExtensionMethods;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using CTixQBIntegration.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
```

Here is my object:

```
public class InvoiceMapping
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string RefNumber { get; set;}
    public string CustomerRef { get; set; }
    public string PONumber { get; set; }
    public string ItemRef { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string Address4 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string ServiceDate { get; set; }
    public string TxnDate { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
DataTable dt = originalDataSource;
            DataTable cl = new DataTable();
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
            List<SourceList> invoiceFields = (from prop in invoice.GetType().GetProperties()
                                              select new SourceList()
                                              {
                                                  FieldName = prop.Name
                                              }).ToList();

            //Check if column names have already been converted
            try
            {
                //Converts Excel Column Names to Quickbooks Column Names
                foreach (var item in invoiceFields)
                {
                    cl.Columns.Add(item.FieldName);
                }
                foreach(var field in invoiceFields)
                {
                    DataRow destRow = cl.NewRow();

                    foreach(DataRow sourcerow in dt.Rows)

                    {
                        foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                        {

                            string colName = col.ColumnName;
                            var mappingField = mapping.GetType().GetProperty(field.FieldName).GetValue(colName);
                            destRow[field.FieldName] = sourcerow[mappingField.ToString()];
                        }

                    }

                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = cl;
            }
```

I need to get value from the "mapping" object where the name of the field is equal to field.fieldName.

I hate adding so much code, but it may help someone to understand the problem.  I have shortened it to show only the first two fields.  This works with everything "hardcoded" as below, the problem, is that I need to make it all dynamic so that it works with ANY datsource:

```
     DataTable dt = originalDataSource;
            DataTable cl = new DataTable();
            cl.Columns.Add("RefNumber");
            cl.Columns.Add("CustomerRef");


            string refnumber = mapping.RefNumber;
            string customerRef = mapping.CustomerRef;

            //Check if column names have already been converted
            try
            {
                //Converts Excel Column Names to Quickbooks Column Names
                foreach (DataRow sourcerow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow destRow = cl.NewRow();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        if (refnumber != "" && refnumber != null)
                        {
                            destRow["RefNumber"] = sourcerow[refnumber];
                        }
                        if (customerRef != "" && customerRef != null)
                        {
                            destRow["CustomerRef"] = sourcerow[customerRef];
                        }

                    }
                    cl.Rows.Add(destRow);
                }
            }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, this? [dynamic property name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42958111/1715579)

Comment: @p.s.w.g I receive the error that my Object does not contain a defintion for 'Select'.  My object is not a list.

Comment: If you just want to get the property value of a single object, just use `obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj)`

Comment: @Ed Plunkett.  The solution to which you refer does not work for me.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff You mean the code you wrote based on that solution doesn't work for you. Since I haven't seen the code you wrote, and I haven't seen the output from that code, it's difficult for me to know how to respond.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett - I wrote:    var mappingField = mapping.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x);  It says "object does not contain a definition for Select".

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unable to guess the type of `mapping`, nor what `using` statements you have. Please provide a minimal but complete, compilable example.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett - I added all that you mentioned.  Please let me know if you require anything else.

Comment: `var mappingField = mapping.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(colName);`.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett - This is still not working.  I added more code above to hopefully better explain my issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I figured out the problem, but since Ed Plunkett marked as a duplicate, I cannot add the answer. The problem, (after given the correct syntax), was not know what needed to go in the "GetValue".  What finally worked is " string mappingField = mapping.GetType().GetProperty(field.FieldName).GetValue(mapping) as string;"  Thank everyone for their assistance.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Bingo! Nailed it. Excellent work.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett- Thank you!  I truly did appreciate all of your help.