# Group and delete repeated data in lists c #

Tags: c#, list

I would like to know how to achieve grouping and eliminating repeated data, for example I have this class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string attrb1{ get; set; }
    public string attrb2{ get; set; }
}
```

and I want to "debug" the repeated objects, try the following, but it does not work.

```
List<MyObject> ListObject = new List<MyObject>();

var obj1 = new MyObject{attrb1="attrb1", attrb2="attrb2"}
ListObject.Add(obj1);

var obj2 = new MyObject{attrb1="attrb1", attrb2="attrb2"}
ListObject.Add(obj2);


List<MyObject> GroupedList= new List<MyObject>();

foreach(var obj in ListObject)
{
    if(!GroupedList.Contains(obj))
        GroupedList.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Reference instances are compared in this case, you need to either implement `IEquatable` or your own equality comparer.

Comment: In your code `GroupedList` is empty so all items inside `ListaObjetos` are added to `GroupedList`

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255121/get-a-list-of-distinct-values-in-list

Comment: obj1 and obj2 are two different instance, though their attributes are equal

Comment: Considered Hashset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, equality between classes is determined by comparing their reference (memory location), so two classes are only equal if they both point to the same instance.

If you want to define a different way of determining equality, then you need to override the `Equals` method (and `GetHashCode`).

It appears that you want to consider two `MyObject` instances equal if both their `attrib1` properties are equal and their `attrib2` properties are equal. If that's the case, you can override `Equals` like so:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string attrb1 { get; set; }
    public string attrb2 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as MyObject;
        return other != null && other.attrb1 == attrb1 && other.attrb2 == attrb2;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (attrb1 + attrb2).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

After this change, the `GroupedList` in your sample code will only contain one item.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `.Distinct()`. To use it for custom objects, you would first need to define 
an [EqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), like so:

```
public class MyObjectComparer : EqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public override bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.attrb1 == y.attrb1 && x.attrb2 == y.attrb2;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        return (obj.attrb1 + obj.attrb2).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as (thus eliminating that for loop entirely):

```
var distinct = ListObject.Distinct(new MyObjectComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2), 
and the following examples in particular:

```
int[] ints1 = { 5, 3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7 };
int[] ints2 = { 8, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 1, 0 };

IEnumerable<int> union = ints1.Union(ints2);
```

and this

```
List<int> ages = new List<int> { 21, 46, 46, 55, 17, 21, 55, 55 };

IEnumerable<int> distinctAges = ages.Distinct();
```

Just make sure you are importing System.Linq

```
using System.Linq
```

Comment: But `Union` and `Distinct` won't work with a `MyObject` as the OP wants since they use the `Equals` method to determine equality...

Comment: They don't have to use it. I don't see it in their code. They can write a comparer as suggested by other answers. But using Distinct or Union is a way to go if you want to select unique values from a collection " eliminating repeated data" as they put it.

Comment: I meant that this answer appears to be suggesting that they modify their sample code to: `IEnumerable<MyObject> GroupedList = ListObject.Distinct();`, and I was saying that this won't work as expected without overriding `Equals` or writing a comparer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be use [`Enumerable.Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2) that will return a new list with the [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) of both sets. To do it, we will need to override [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2) to be sure that only the properties will be compared and not references

To make it easier, we will use [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
/// <summary>
/// Inherit from interface <see cref="IEquatable{T}"/>
/// </summary>
public class Objeto : IEquatable<Objeto>
{
    public string atributo1 { get; set; }
    public string atributo2 { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Implements <see cref="Equals(Objeto)"/> method from interface <see cref="IEquatable{T}"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">The second object we will compare.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Equals(Objeto other)
    {
        //If the object is null, are not equal.
        if(other==null)return false;
        //If isn't null we compare both attributes.
        return atributo1==other.atributo1&&atributo2==other.atributo2;
    }

    //Override Equals calling the Equals(Object) implementation.
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Objeto);

    //override GetHashCode making sure that if Equals is true, both objects must have the same HashCode.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return atributo1.GetHashCode() ^ atributo2.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now, we can use [`Enumerable.Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.7.2) with objects of type `Objeto`

```
List<Objeto> list1 = new List<Objeto>{new Objeto{atributo1="Dato1", atributo2 = "Dato2"}};
List<Objeto> list2 = new List<Objeto>
{
    new Objeto{atributo1="Dato1", atributo2 = "Dato2"},
    new Objeto{atributo1="Dato3", atributo2 = "Dato4"}
};

//Get the unión between both lists
var listaDefinitiva = list1.Union(list2);

foreach (var objeto in listaDefinitiva)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Atributo1: {0}\t Atributo2: {1}",objeto.atributo1,objeto.atributo2);
}
```

The console output will be

> ```
> Atributo1: Dato1         Atributo2: Dato2
> Atributo1: Dato3         Atributo2: Dato4
> ```