# How to group by 2 items of a list into another list

Tags: c#, linq

As for this example:

[Get a list of distinct values in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255121/get-a-list-of-distinct-values-in-list)

This demonstrates how to get a distinct list based on 1 item.

How do you get a distinct list of 2 things. Say Author and title.

```
public class Note
{
    public string Title;
    public string Author;
    public string Text;
}

List<Note> Notes = new List<Note>();
```

The answer for one is:

```
Notes.Select(x => x.Author).Distinct();
```

Comment: Notes.Select(x => new string[] {x.Author,x.Title}).Distinct();

Comment: do you mean x.Author,x.Title?

Comment: I corrected code

Comment: thank you. Can you put as answer so this will close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jdweng suggested in the comments you can do:

```
Notes.Select(x => new string[] {x.Title, x.Author}).Distinct();
```

which will return a `IEnumerable<string[]>`.

Another option is to create a class to select into:

```
public class NoteSummary()
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public NoteSummary(string title, string author)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
    }
}
```

Then the linq becomes:

```
Notes.Select(x => new NoteSummary(x.Title, x.Author)).Distinct();
```

which returns `IEnumerable<NoteSummary>`.

If you want to return a grouped collection of the original `Note` class/entity you can use `GroupBy`:

```
Notes
  .GroupBy(g => new { g.Title, g.Author })  // group by fields
  .Select(g => g.First());                  // select first group
```

which returns `IEnumerable<Note>`.

Comment: I think this is going to answer my follow on question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55423245/after-getting-distinct-list-using-the-results-in-a-query