# Distinct Column in SelectList for dropdown list

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I am retrieving distinct values from a table against only one column. when I debug ViewData in controller it has retrieved the values perfectly, but in my view it says Object is not referenced. can some one help me out.

I think the dataValueField and dataTextField are not named "TeamName" anymore after distinct is applied. how to name selected column of my choice so that below SelectList could work. thanks

**Controller**

```
ViewData["TeamNames"] = new SelectList(_context.ActivityMaps.Select(s => s.TeamName).Distinct(), "TeamName", "TeamName", model.TeamName);
```

**View**

```
<select asp-for="TeamName" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TeamNames"></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `TeamName` is string type.

```
_context.ActivityMaps.Select(s => s.TeamName).Distinct().ToList()
```

So the above query just return a list of string, and it doesn't have `TeamName` property.

Just remove the dataValueField and dataTextField.

```
ViewData["TeamNames"] = new SelectList(_context.ActivityMaps.Select(s => s.TeamName).Distinct().ToList(), model.TeamName);
```

**Update:**

```
var names = _db.ActivityMaps.Select(s => s.TeamName).Distinct().Select(n => new { TeamName = n }).ToList();

ViewData["TeamNames"] = new SelectList(names, "TeamName", "TeamName", model.TeamName);
```

Comment: yes it works, but can you show me how to name a property?